# Google Map is refreshed

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have google map API which is wroking fine in Chrome, Mozilla, Netscape and safari but there is a problem in IE, once I enter the text in text area and clicked search link it is not showing me the address rather just getting refreshed. Please could any one provide me a solution for this.

Thanks and Regards,
Syed Zubair.

Comment: Can you add a link to what you have so far? Or - better yet! - really, really edit what you have so far, get rid of everything that isn't related to this problem, and then give us a link to the simplified version?

Comment: I think we have to know one thing first: is your textarea located in a <form>? If it is, it looks like your form is submitted. If your textarea is in a form, I suppose you have some JavaScript to prevent form submit and do something instead. If this is the case, you probably have a JS error that prevents this piece of code to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing something like the following?

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSearch();">Search!</a>
```

Your problem that IE is following the link when you click on it, thus causing the page to reload. Traditionally, people have often worked around this by doing the following:

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="doSearch(); return false;">Search!</a>
```

But I've had mixed results with that in IE. Instead, try using a `<span>` instead of an  tag and then style it to look like a link (that is, use text-decoration:underline and color:blue in CSS). If switching from an anchor tag to a span fixes it, then you know that's the problem.

My personal preference is to reserve `<a>` tags only for actual links to other pages or real anchors in the page.